# Exception while mapping object to interface using .As()

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

Automapper threw following error while mapping

```
public class ServiceProfile : Profile
    {
        public ServiceProfile()
        {
            this.CreateMap<ClassA, IClassB>().As<ClassB>();
        }
    }
```

Error: Missing map from ClassA to ClassB. Create using CreateMap<ClassA, ClassB>

Thats with 12.1.0 version. On version 7.0.0 that works just fine. I cannot find any mentions on automapper docs about IMappingExpression changes.

ClassB is inherited from IClassB. Should i first create map this.CreateMap<ClassA, IClassB>() then this.CreateMap<ClassA, ClassB>()?